# Permission denied when querying a GCP BigQuery Table that is connected to Google Sheets with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, permissions

I've got my NodeJS script that works perfectly when querying any BigQuey table with a specific Service Account that has the following Roles:

```
BigQuery Admin
BigQuery Data Editor
BigQuery Data Viewer
BigQuery Job User
Editor
Service Account Token Creator
```

(I know these are excessive, but I was testing and I still got the Access Denied error)

When I query a table that is **connected to a Google Sheets document**, I get this error

`Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.`

I created the BigQuery Table like this:

1. Create table from: Drive
2. Drive URI: My Google Sheets table URI
3. File format: Google sheet
4. Sheet range: My sheet name
5. Auto-detect schema
6. Header rows to skip: 1

So it's not connected from Google Sheets, is done from BigQuery because I want to be able to edit the table from Google Sheets so if I query my BigQuery table I get that updated content.

I've already given access to my Service Account email to the Google Sheet document, I even made it public to test and nothing.

So, basically this is what's happening

- NodeJS -> BigQuery Table -> NodeJS ✅
- NodeJS -> BigQuery Table -> Google Sheets ❌ (Permission denied)

What am I missing? What Role should I give to my Service Account to access Google Sheets through a BigQuery SQL query?

Note: I've also checked the logs from GCP of my Service Account and I can see that I'm querying from NodeJS with the correct key.

Comment: When you create a connection, you should have a service account automatically generated with this connection. Grant this service account the permission to read your Google Sheet document (in the Google Sheet -> share -> Use SA email and grant it as viewer)

Comment: How can I find that self-created service account? I'm looking into IAM & Admin >  Service Accounts and I can't find any that was created by itself

Comment: My bad, the connection to Google Sheet is not yet managed by external connection. So, for now, you can't achieve what you want.

Comment: You mean is not possible to connect to a BQ Table that's done from a Google Sheets with a NodeJS script? What could be some alternatives to achieve what I need?

Comment: Does your service account have the Permission `roles/dataflow.admin` and `roles/dataflow.worker` roles aside from viewer access ?

Comment: Im trying almost the same thing and can't get rid of the drive permission denied. Also using nodejs-bigquery. And a while ago got the same issue when I was connecting datagrip to BQ (GoogleSheets). Please let us know if you find any workaround.

Comment: OK, so now I tried something that works (in my case), but its a workaround.
1. In BigQuery, create a QUERY that periodically save the result in a table. Now, from node.js you are dealing with BigQuery instead of google sheets. Anyway, please let us know if you find something.

Comment: Does this [Link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-drive) will help you ?

Comment: Did help because after reading I ended using the python library that allows me to authenticate as service account with keyfile. I guess Nodejs also can, but I am more familiarized with python. Plus, it allow you to add scopes at the authentication point, so I added "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly" and worked as a charm. Thanks!