# Using Google Workflow to query a Google Sheet through Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workflows

I am using a cloud workflow orchestration to query a Bigquery table, which is connected to a Google Sheet, on google drive as an external table.

So cloud workflow uses service account `<SA_ID>@<ProjectName>.iam.gserviceaccount.com` to query the said bigquery table. I have provided Editor access to the SA in the google sheet, and Admin access to the SA in Bigquery.  While the workflow is working with a native bigquery table, when querying a table conencted to google sheet I get following error `Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.`
Is a service account not supposed to access a google sheet?

Comment: Pretty similar to this question and for now, you can't achieve this. Connection to Google Drive is not managed by external connection, and therefore there isn't a dedicated service account to achieve the connection. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76702582/permission-denied-when-querying-a-gcp-bigquery-table-that-is-connected-to-google/76703469?noredirect=1#comment135235003_76703469

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere.  I did review that query, and it was in the same vein.  It just seemed extremely handicaped to me if a native tool in GCP is not allowed to access Google drive.  Note I can achieve the same if I run a scheduled query with a service account though.  Wonder if this is part of a feature request yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki so that others can benefit from it.

---

As mentioned by @guillaume blaquiere:

> Pretty similar to this question and for now, you can't achieve this. Connection to Google Drive is not managed by external connection, and therefore there isn't a dedicated service account to achieve the connection. [Permission denied when querying a GCP BigQuery Table that is connected to Google Sheets with NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76702582/permission-denied-when-querying-a-gcp-bigquery-table-that-is-connected-to-google/76703469?noredirect=1#comment135235003_76703469)

---

You may file a feature request in this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

**Note**: The Product team will investigate and check if this is a valid feature request. There is no ETA for it, though. Once you create a feature request you may also track the updates of your request on that same link.